# Ctypes: Could not find module ( Shared Library ) to use C-Code in Python

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes

I am currently working to get some intuition about interfacing `C-Code` to `Python`. For interfacing C-code to Python, I am using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module and following these implementations such that:

- [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145649/10413749)
- [How to Call a C function in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-call-a-c-function-in-python/).

As we know that

> The ctypes module provides C compatible data types and functions to
>   load DLLs so that calls can be made to C shared libraries without
>   having to modify them.

I have just implemented a simple function using `C` and generated " *Shared Library* " of the file using these commands on [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/):

```
For Linux, 
- cc -fPIC -shared -o libfunc.so function.c
- gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,adder -o adder.so -fPIC function.c

On Windows, assuming that you have GCC installed: 
1 ~ $ gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -fPIC function.c -o libfunc.o
2 ~ $ gcc -shared libfunc.o -o libfunc.dll
```

Then I placed all the files in the *same directory*. Following are given files:

- function.c
- libfunc.so
- Testing.py

### function.c

```
int func(int num) 
{
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

### Testing.py

```
import os
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library


num = 16
# To verify that Library is available in the specified path
pathToWin32Environment = os.getcwd()
pathToDll = pathToWin32Environment + "\\libfunc.so"
if not os.path.exists(pathToDll):
    raise Exception('Could not locate ' + pathToDll)

curr_dir_before = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(pathToWin32Environment)

# print("Available library:", find_library('libfunc.so'))


Lib_func = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("F:/PythonCodeBase/NetEQ/libfunc.so")
# Lib_func = ctypes.CDLL(F:/PythonCodeBase/NetEQ/libfunc.so")
# Lib_func = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("libfunc.so")

Lib_func.func.argtypes(ctypes.c_int)
ret_val = Lib_func.func(num)

print(ret_val)
```

---

I have tried many times, either I'm giving the `full Specified path` or simple `(.so) filename`. Every time, I just got these types of errors.

```
- FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'F:\PythonCodeBase\NetEQ\libfunc.so'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
- FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libfunc.so'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I have done multiple attempts using `PyCharm IDE` as well as `Command Prompt` but the same error appears. 
Please assist me accordingly.

Comment: What's the environment you're using? Cause it looks like a *Win* machine, but details are *Nix* specific.

Comment: @CristiFati Yes. I am using the Win machine (Microsoft Windows 10 Pro). But I am compiling the *Shared Library* using [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on windows.

Comment: Then try: ***/cygdrive/f/PythonCodeBase/NetEQ/libfunc.so*** (or *./libfunc.so* - relative). Also I assume that you launched the *Python* that comes with *Cigwin*, not some regular *Win* one.

Comment: @CristiFati, I have tried all of these paths: 1. `./libfunc.so`, 2. `/cygdrive/f/PythonCodeBase/NetEQ/libfunc.so`, 3. `F:\\PythonCodeBase\\NetEQ\\libfunc.so` . Apart from these, if my library is compiled then I think, after providing the library location, *Ctypes* should work on windows. As in the documentation of *ctypes*, they haven't told about something like use *the compiled platform related python stuff*. Secondly, I have tried this using cygwin python. But It didn't work as well.

Comment: loool, just took a closer look. You name your file ***libfun.so***, but you're searching for *libfun**c**.so*.

Comment: @CristiFati, Just spelling mistake. *I have corrected it*. But fortunately, I am using *libfunc.so* and I also have compiled it with this name *libfunc.so*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210656/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-and-cristifati).